# site-to-site VPN between Windows Azure and Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, vpn

I've seen quite a couple of posts giving guidance on how to create a site-to-site VPN on your local network, but does anyone know how it would be possible to setup a site-to-site VPN between a Windows Azure network and a Amazon Private Cloud?  In an ideal world it would be great to achieve this without needing an appliance somewhere to connect the two networks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, let me say I've not tried this at all.  You may be able to do this, but it looks like you might be blazing a trail here so expect some issues and some trial and error.

As you have likely already seen the list of supported devices are listed out here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156075#bkmk_untested and all are devices; however, the requirements for what the VPN must do is as follows:

- VPN device must have a public facing IPv4 address

  VPN device must support IKEv1

  Establish IPsec Security Associations in Tunnel mode

  VPN device must support NAT-T

  VPN device must support AES 128-bit encryption function, SHA-1
  hashing function, and Diffie-Hellman Perfect Forward Secrecy in
  "Group 2" mode

  VPN device must fragment packets before encapsulating with the VPN
  headers

  UDP port 500, UDP port 4500 and ESP packets must be permitted to
  traverse the network edge (open ACLs in the edge to allow these
  protocols / ports)

They note that while the Juniper and Cisco devices are the only ones supported they don't rule out that other devices and/or software solutions working.  Other options just aren't supported and they won't provide the scripts and handy step by step instructions on getting them set up.  If you are interested enough to try getting something working and don't mind not getting support if something goes wrong, then you can continue from here.

If you can find a software VPN solution that meets the requirements above then you may just be able to pull this off.  Here is a link to a blog post where someone got it working using the Threat Management Gateway (TMG): http://blog.kloud.com.au/2012/07/25/windows-azure-virtual-network-vpn-with-tmg-2010/ .  Note that the TMG has been discontinued, but at least this is an example of someone using a software VPN solution which is the first step in your scenario.

The second hurdle might be the fact that you need a public IP that is not behind a NAT.  I'm not overly familiar with Amazon, but I believe this means you'll likely want to look at an EIP (Elastic IP address) so that the IP is static, publicly addressable and will remain consistent even if you have to stop or redeploy your EC2 instance.

The idea would be to get a VPN software solution that meets the requirements above, set that up on an EC2 instance with an EIP and then determine the configuration needed for Azure VPN.  For now that's the best I can suggest.  If you get it working you should definitely blog about it as indeed this could be a very good option for those wanting to stretch across the vendors for a whole host of reasons.

Comment: I've not tried it either, but I wonder if there's a way to hook up directly to the Amazon VPC: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a "Customer Gateway" server on Azure to connect to an Amazon VPC like this where the words "your data center or network" here will be Azure.

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html

Alternatively you can setup a RRAS server on Amazon EC2 like this where "On-Site" here refers to your Amazon VPC:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636917.aspx

Comment: Why was this voted down ? How can I help improve ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very detailed walkthrough of how to set it up:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/01/11/step-by-step-connect-your-aws-and-azure-environments-with-a-vpn-tunnel/